# Why does my cat acts weird and undisciplined in front of guests?

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat always behaves so well and listens to me. But when someone comes to my home she starts acting so stupid. She runs here and there and get out of control and do  every possible weird acts. What should I do to control this behavior of him?

Comment: Could you describe the weird behavior in more detail? I'm currently guessing it could be a stress reaction, like hyperesthesia https://www2.vet.cornell.edu/departments-centers-and-institutes/cornell-feline-health-center/health-information/feline-health-topics/hyperesthesia-syndrome or some sort, but it's impossible to know without knowing more details about the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your cat has some anxiety about there being a stranger in his or her living space. Cats react strongly to unfamiliar scents, especially, if your human guest has pets of their own. Your cat could be reacting to that. When I come home from the house of a friend who has cats, my cats sniff my jacket and shoes for a long time.

Some cats just aren't outgoing and only want to be around the humans who love them and feed them. My friend Abby has to close her cat in the bedroom when certain friends come over, because her cat has a strong and sometimes violent reaction to certain people. You could try having your friends offer a cat treat to your cat; sometimes bribery works. But it's not a sure thing the way it is with dogs.

Answer (score 1):

Cats can get anxiety around new people! Chances are, this is her way of telling you that she doesn't like this person, who, in her eyes, is an intruder. She doesn't know that they were invited by you; in her eyes, this person showed up out of nowhere, and is going to be staying for God knows how long in *her* territory.

Unfortunately, not a whole lot can be done to tame these anxieties-- in my experience, I've found that for relatively short visits, shutting the cat in the bedroom can help give them some peace. Make sure they have food, water, and a place to potty while they're trapped, or you could find yourself on the receiving end of a very stinky "gift" on the floor in retaliation.

If the guest is someone you want to have over frequently, or even potentially move in (like a roommate or significant other), then it's a good idea to try and get the two acquainted. Use treats, grooming tools that she fancies, new toys, or catnip as an incentive to try and get close to the new person-- then hand those tools over to your guest! Have patience, and your baby might end up warming up to this person after a bit.